# Magento2.1 search

Tags: magento-2.1, attributes, search

After import attributes with magmi in magento2, search function is not working. It always  shows no search result found in search result page.
Reindex didn't help me

Comment: Had similar issue a while with magmi ended up having to use standard import

Comment: Did you find solution? @DavaGordon